# Getting 401.2 when certificate authentication is enabled

Tags: iis, iis-7, certificate

I'm setting up a server so that only mapped certificates can get to the webservice.  It is set to require SSL/Client certificates, anonymous authentication, asp.net impersonation, forms authentication, and windows authentication are all disabled.  One-to-one client certificate mapping is enabled, and certs are set up on the box with an appropriate user mapping.  When I try to use the webservice, I get 401.2.  If I enable anonymous authentication, it works, but I don't want any old cert to be able to access the website.

I have another machine that has anonymous authentication disabled in this configuration, and it works.  I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Can you clarify this sentence: "It is set to require SSL/Client certificates, anonymous authentication, asp.net impersonation, forms authentication, and windows authentication are all disabled."

It is not clear what is and is not enabled in your configuration. Also, what versions of IIS, Windows, and what browsers are you working with?

Comment: @natemrice - Certainly. IIS 7, Server 2008, and I've tried IE and Chrome, but since this is a .Net 2.0 WebService, the access is specifically from a program. For the clarification: If you go into the IIS manager and click on the desired website:
1) Under "Authentication" you find Anonymous Authentication, ASP.Net Impersonation, Forms Authentication, Windows Authentication.  Only Anonymous is enabled, I would like to have it disabled.
2) Click back on the website and go to SSL Settings and I have "Require SSL" checked and Client Certificates is set to "Require"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being the software that was calling in, not in the configuration.  I'm awarding natemrice the bounty since he put in a good effort to answer what ended up being a non-question.

edit: For more information, it actually ended up being a mismatch between the cert being sent (from the local box) and the cert that was put in the oneToOne mappings.  The common name was the same, but the certs were different (likely the first one expired) so the cert simply wasn't authorized.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem, but the solution above did not solve my problem.  I was configuring IIS Certificate Authentication on a subdirectory of the website, not on the website itself.

So, this is wrong:

[image: Wrong usage]

And this is correct:

[image: Correct usage]

Once I moved the configuration to the root of the website, everything worked perfectly.

I found the solution at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2009/06/13/avoid-this-confusion-around-client-certificate-mapping-in-iis-6-0-7-0.aspx.

Comment: This is the hint I was looking for!! I just tried it on IIS7.5 and the certificate-to-user mappings only works at the root level of the site. But you can configure it and leave it disabled at the root and then enable it only on the alias you need to work with, without repeating the mappings..

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stucked for days with this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Did you issue your client certs from a Certificate Server that the clients/server trust? If you look at the "Enhanced Key Usage" property on the certificates, is "Client Authentication" one of it's properties? In IIS, is the client certificate mapping role installed (see image 1)? did you enable "[Client Certificate Mapping](http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/04/27/configuring-many-to-one-client-certificate-mappings-for-iis-7-7-5.aspx)" and map the users to the certificate? You need to import all of the client certificates and map them to user accounts here. You can remove all of the other client authentication methods when you have configured that here.

[image]

Comment: The certificates are trusted (as an aside, this couldn't possibly be the issue since the website immediately rejects the requests saying that you can't connect because of the server configuration (the 401.2 code)).  In system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication, enabled is set to true, manyToOne..enabled is set to true, and oneToOne..enabled is set to true.  There are certificates set up in the oneToOneMappings collection.

Comment: The problem is 1 of 2 things: 1) You still have all those other auth mechanisms on, they should all be off, or 2) Your client mappings are screwed up somehow. The client certs don't match the server, incorrect user, etc.